# Blocked by CORS policy error when downloading file in angular app from .net mvc api controller

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am trying to download file from asp.net web api from an angular 8 application and getting CORS error. CORS is enabled for all controllers my web api. If i don't return stream then it works fine, CORS error start throwing when api return stream.

API Code:-

```
    var stream = new MemoryStream(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    response.ClearContent();
    response.Clear();
    response.Buffer = true;
    response.Charset = "";
    response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

    var data = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    stream.Close();
    response.BinaryWrite(data);
    response.Flush();
    response.End();
```

angular code:-

```
let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob, headers });
this.http.get(url,{  observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'} ).subscribe((response)=>{
const blob = new Blob([response.body],
{ type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
const file = new File([blob], 'reports.xlxs',
{ type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
saveAs(file);
});
```

I start getting below error as soon as subscribe is being called. When i debug it execute all the code of api and return below error.

Error:- 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:19119//offers/42428/export/orderDetails' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should enable **CORS** in the asp.net app. It's a server-side error.

In Visual Studio, from the Tools menu, select NuGet Package Manager, then select Package Manager Console. In the Package Manager Console window, type the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

for more information about how to enable CORS in your web API, see the following link please:

[Enable cross-origin requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

Adding below line of code to HttpResponse solved my problem.

```
response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```